# Calculating how many pieces fit into a given area

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any program which calculates how many pieces of an item with different sizes you can put in one area?

For example, I have a sheet of glass with size $3210 \times 2210$mm. Now I have different sizes to cut:

- $1800 \times 1200=5$pcs,
- $600 \times 800=14$pcs,
- $400 \times 500=15$pcs,
- $900 \times 500=10$pcs.

I want to maximize the use of sheet so to as to avoid big wastage. Can you help me find any program or any formula?

Comment: Such a question is about "2D bin packing". It has been discussed several times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880975/is-there-a-c-source-lib-to-solve-2d-bin-packing-with-a-rectangular-bin-not-sq/15451508#15451508

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350120/fitting-random-sized-rectangles-into-larger-rectangle/350571#350571), I've arrived at the following packing:

[image]

I've added the following lines of Javascript to function `doRender()` in [RectanglePacker](http://pollinimini.net/demos/RectanglePacker.html):

(notice that I scaled down all dimensions by a factor of 10)

```
params.canvasWidth = 321;
params.canvasHeight = 221;
var b = []
var i = 0;
var bi = 0;
b[i++] = { w: 180, h: 120, n: 5 };
b[i++] = { w: 60, h: 80, n: 14 };
b[i++] = { w: 40, h: 50, n: 15 };
b[i++] = { w: 90, h: 50, n: 10 };

for (var j=0; j<b.length; j++) {
    for (var n=0; n<b[j].n; n++) {
        blocks[bi++] = { w: b[j].w, h: b[j].h };
    }
}
```